# Seeking R Package for GINI Coefficient Calculation with Zero and Negative Values

Tags: economics

I'm working on calculating the GINI coefficient in R to analyze various aspects of wealth inequality. Specifically, I am interested in decomposing GINI by different subgroups. However, my data includes zero and negative values, and I haven't discovered an R package capable of handling these. In contrast, Stata has a package called [INEQDEC0](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s366007.html)  that accounts for these values. Does anyone know of an equivalent package in R?

Comment: hi, if you have survey data (like the datasets from asdfree.com) you could use the [R convey package](https://guilhermejacob.github.io/context/)  ..i'm not sure there's a method to _decompose_ the gini by subgroup, you might need a different measure like `svygei`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on [wINEQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wINEQ/index.html) package. Looks it works with 0 and negative values:

```
wINEQ::Gini(X= c(1:10))
#> [1] 0.3
wINEQ::Gini(X= c(-10:1))
#> [1] -0.441358
wINEQ::Gini(X= c(10, 2, -10, -7, 0, 0))
#> [1] -4.233333

wINEQ::Gini(X= c(-10:10))
#> [1] NaN
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The last `NaN` result is caused by median value of `c(-10:10)` which is `0` and it's used in denominator of gini cooeficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am specifically interested in decomposing the inequality of GINI by subgroups. The package you suggested, while great, it does make the decomposition by subgroups